# Numpy way of spliting a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a (n x k) dimensional matrix X, and a (n x 1) dimensional matrix Y. My question is that using NumPy how can I split the matrix X based on the element on the same index in the Y matrix. Sample data in them can be like:

```
    X      ,   Y
[ 1.4  0.2], ['class_A']
[ 1.3  0.2], ['class_B']
[ 1.5  0.2], ['class_C']
[ 1.4  0.2], ['class_a']
[ 1.7  0.4], ['class_A']
[ 1.4  0.3], ['class_B']
[ 1.5  0.2], ['class_C']
.........
```

I have tried it using simple python, but I want to do it through NumPy, but I didn't find any function for this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can index over a boolean array, for example:

```
In [8]: import numpy as np

In [9]: X = np.arange(16).reshape(8, 2)

In [10]: Y = np.array([0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1])

In [11]: X[Y == 1]
Out[11]: 
array([[ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [14, 15]]
```